# Como criar div dinamicamente com a mesma class usando js

Tags: javascript, html

Estou criando um projeto porem não sei muito sobre "js" , Minha Funcao retorna uma array percorro o array com "for" e filtro os valores , porem preciso cria divs dinamicamente com mesma classe , mudado apenas o innerText  ,

exemplo :

```
<div class=list>
   <div class='icon'><img class='img'src='foto.png'</div>
   <li class='valor'>valor1</li>
<div>
```

meu codigo :

```
for (i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
         div = document.querySelector('.list')
         precoTOTAL = div.innerHTML;
         console.log(precoTOTAL)
         
         var s3 = precoTOTAL.replace(/[\D]+/g,'');
 
         var valor = parseInt(s3); 
         var garrafa = valor / 600;
         HTMLNovo ='<div class="option_feature">Preço para 6 unidades<br>Cada garrafa por R$ '+garrafa.toFixed(2)+'</div>';
         HTMLcont = '<div class="inco_chanel"></div>'
         div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', HTMLNovo);
```

Sendo assim consigo cria apenas o 'list' mas não consigo por outra div dentro da mesma , pois , só a primeira list se aplica mas o resto não , acho que o js so esta pegando somente uma div, criando as demais nela ,

Comment: Desculpa não entendi o seu problema. Aqui `div = document.querySelector('.list')` a cada iteração a variável `div` irá referenciar `<div class=list>` e em `div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', HTMLNovo);` o html dinâmico será adicionado ao final do elemento referenciado por `div`?

Comment: Opan amigo , perdão acabei de resolver esse problema , como sou meio leigo em js não deu para explica bem , resolução foi a seguinte , eu simplesmente implementei mais código de divs dentro do HTMLNovo = "<div class=option><li>texto</li></div>" assim pude cria quantas divs eu quiser , e implementar os valores, Sei que não e o melhor jeito de se criar divs dinamicamente